# JavaScript replace() if string found between startIndex and endIndex as substring() does

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some HTML in my DOM and I want to replace some strings in it, but only if that was not already replaced or that is not a TAG.

All that is based on an Array that contains the string I want to find and the new string I want this to be replace with.

Work in progress: https://jsfiddle.net/u2Lyaab1/23/

**UPDATE: The HTML markup is just for simplicity written with ULs in the sample code, BUT it can contain different tags, event different nesting levels**

Basically the `desiredReplcement` works nice (except that it looks in tags too), but I want that to happen on the DOM, not the new string because I want to maintain any other HTML markup in the DOM.

**SNIPPET**:

```js
var list = [{
    original: 'This is',
    new: 'New this is'
  },
  {
    original: 'A list',
    new: 'New A list'
  },
  {
    original: 'And I want',
    new: 'New And I want'
  },
  {
    original: 'To wrap',
    new: 'New To wrap'
  },
  {
    original: 'li',
    new: 'bold'
  },
  {
    original: 'This',
    new: 'New This'
  },
  {
    original: 'strong',
    new: 'bold'
  },  {
original: 'This is another random tag',
new: 'This is another random tag that should be bold'
  }

];


var div = $('.wrap');
var htmlString = div.html();
var index = 0;
list.forEach(function(item, index) {

  console.log(index + ' Should replace: "' + item.original + '" with "' + item.new + '"');

  //I know that there is something here, but not sure what
  index = htmlString.indexOf(item.original);
  var expressionLength = index + item.original.length;
  var substring = htmlString.substring(index, expressionLength);
  var desiredReplcement = substring.replace(item.original, '<strong>' + item.new + '</strong>');
  console.log('index', index);
  console.log('substring', substring);
  console.log('desiredReplcement', desiredReplcement);

  //Current implementation in replace looks in the full div, but I just want to replace in the substring mathced above;
  var replacement = '<strong>' + item.new + '</strong>';
  var newHTML = div.html().replace(item.original, replacement);
  div.html(newHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <ul>
    <li>This is</li>
    <li>A list</li>
    <li>And I want</li>
    <li>This should not be bold</li>
    <li>To wrap</li>
    <li>This</li>
    <li>strong</li>
    <li>li</li>
  </ul>
<span><p><em>This is another random tag</em></p></span>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: An alternative by converting the list into a Map: https://jsfiddle.net/u2Lyaab1/12/

Comment: I updated my question. The answer must be applicable for all sort of HTML content.

Comment: So, you want to check the entire DOM for these strings? What happens if there are multiples, or if one of those stings happen to make up part of other words? What are the target use cases, and what is the ultimate goal you are looking to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that jQuery is necessary here.

First, you want to retrieve your container, which in your case will be the `.wrap` div.

```
var container = document.querySelector('.wrap');
```

Then you want to create a recursive function that will loop through an array to search and replace the data provided.

```
function replacement(containers, data){

    if(!data || !data.length)
        return;

    for(let i=0; i<containers.length; i++){

        var container = containers[i];

        // Trigger the recursion on the childrens of the current container
        if(container.children.length)
            replacement(container.children, data);

        // Perform the replacement on the actual container
        for(let j=0; j<data.length; j++){
            var index = container.textContent.indexOf(data[j].original);

            // Data not found
            if(index === -1)
                continue;

            // Remove the data from the list
            var replace = data.splice(j, 1)[0];
            container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML.replace(replace.original, '<strong>' + replace.new + '</strong>');

            // Lower the j by 1 since the data array length has been updated
            j--;

            // Only want to perform one rule
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/u2Lyaab1/25/

Comment: Very nice! One thing I noticed is that the one sentence "This should not be bold" is't been made bold in the first part of the string

Comment: @AdrianFlorescu What do you mean? In the fiddle I see "New This should not be bold" and the "New This" is in bold.

Comment: yes, the that full sentance should not be replaced at all

Comment: Also, in the result panel, I noticed a string that reads: "New A boldst"

Comment: @AdrianFlorescu Hmm... why should that sentence not be replaced tho? Isn't it a simple element like all the other li? Also, the "New a boldst" is because it replaced the "li" from the "list". Because one of the object is original set to `li` and new set to `bold`. So the `li` of `list` becomes `boldst`.

Comment: You can remove the "<li>This should not be bold</li>" from the initial DOM, but the "boldst" should not be there -- the script should replace the original strings in the DOM with the new ones from the object in JS

Comment: @AdrianFlorescu That's what it's doing. It replaced the first line with "New a list", then replaced the "li"  from the "list" to "bold". Do you want the rules to not overwrite each other?

Comment: Yes - I mentioned in my question: "but only if that was not already replaced or that is not a TAG" -- not sure if that was clear enough in my question.

Comment: @AdrianFlorescu Alright, I've updated my answer to not have rules overwriting each other.

Comment:  You are awesome! Thank you very much for your time! It's perfect!

Answer (score 3):

Your `div` variable is referencing `<div class="wrap">...</div>`, therefore your `htmlString` value is a group of html tags instead of string.

That is the main reason your code is not working as expected.

And therefore I rewrote your implementation.

```js
var list = [
  {
    original: 'This is',
    new: 'New this is'
  },
  {
    original: 'A list',
    new: 'New A list'
  },
  {
    original: 'And I want',
    new: 'New And I want'
  },
  {
    original: 'To wrap',
    new: 'New To wrap'
  },
  {
    original: 'li',
    new: 'bold'
  },
  {
    original: 'This',
    new: 'New This'
  },
  {
    original: 'strong',
    new: 'bold'
  }
  
];

var div = document.getElementsByClassName('wrap')[0].getElementsByTagName('li');  // Getting all <li> elements within <div class="wrap">

Array.prototype.forEach.call(div, function(li, x){  // Borrowing Array's forEach method to be used on HTMLCollection

    list.forEach(function(value, i){                // Looping through list
        if (value.original === li.innerHTML)        // if list[i]['original'] === li[x].innerHTML
            li.innerHTML = '<strong>' + value.new + '</strong>';
            
    });
    
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <ul>
     <li>This is</li>
     <li>A list</li>
     <li>And I want</li>
     <li>This should not be bold</li>
     <li>To wrap</li>
     <li>This</li>
     <li>strong</li>
     <li>li</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You can improve performance here by having your map be `var list = {'This is':'New this is', ...}` - ie. a "search=>replace" map. That way you don't need the inner loop, just get `list[li.innerHTML]` (or, better, `li.textContent`)

Comment: @YongQuan. Thank you forr your answer! The DOM might contain any TAG.... so your solution is good just for this particular case, any thoungs if I had some random tags instead of list items?

Comment: @AdrianFlorescu sure, you can get some idea from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childnodes.asp) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_children.asp)

Comment: Wow, you are a clever man! :D, but what if there is no chidren, and it's directly text?

Comment: @AdrianFlorescu you can find any kinds of contents using the `childNode` property from the first link. To filter or find certain type of nodes, refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodetype.asp). For element, `nodeType === 1`. For text, `nodeType === 3`.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will not replace tags and will do only one replacement for one text node (if there is any match). It looks through the whole structure in a recursive manner and checks the text of the elements.(and it uses the same list you described in your question)

Requirements:

1. Replace text just in case of exact match => use === instead of indexOf
2. Replace text only once => remove item from list after use

   ```
   var div = $('.wrap');

   function substitute(htmlElement, substituteStrings){
     var childrenElements = htmlElement.children;
     if(childrenElements.length !== 0){
       for (let i=0;i<childrenElements.length;i++){
           substitute(childrenElements[i], substituteStrings);
       }
     } else {
       var htmlString = htmlElement.innerText;
       substituteStrings.some(function(item){
           if(htmlString == item.original){
               htmlElement.innerHTML = htmlString.replace(item.original, '<strong>' + item.new + '</strong>');
               substituteStrings.splice(index,1);
               return true;
           }
       });
     }
   }
   substitute(div[0],list);
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works almost perfect: https://jsfiddle.net/gLz7w5ax/ but as you can see, the last sentence is replaced differently than the expected in the list

Comment: That's true. Could you define the desired behavior when multiple (maybe partial) matching occur?

Comment: Basically the replacement needs to happen only one time and if it's not an exact match do not add the wrapper tags replacements

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to use recursion to search through every nested node in the parent node.

My answer (partial answer) has the same results as [Zsolt V's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46373319/8535397), but is a little less elegant.

Zsolt V has checked child nodes, and it can therefore work with innerHTML by using HTML tags. I on the other hand have checked if a node is a textNode, and have built the replacement nodes using the DOM (pure DOM solution) and nodes' textContent property.

```
var list = [{
    original: 'This is',
    new: 'New this is'
  }, {
    original: 'A list',
    new: 'New A list'
  }, {
    original: 'And I want',
    new: 'New And I want'
  }, {
    original: 'To wrap',
    new: 'New To wrap'
  }, {
    original: 'li',
    new: 'bold'
  }, {
    original: 'This',
    new: 'New This'
  }, {
    original: 'strong',
    new: 'bold'
  }, {
    original: 'This is another random tag',
    new: 'This is another random tag that should be bold'
  }

];


//I want for each expression in this array, to find that expression in array, replace-it and make-it bold with a <strong> tag.

var div = document.getElementsByClassName("wrap")[0];

function processNode(node) {
  if (node.nodeName === "#text") {
    list.forEach(function(item, index) {
      if (node.parentNode && node.textContent.indexOf(item.original) > -1) {
        //node.textContent = node.textContent.replace(item.original, item.new);

        let untouched = node.textContent.split(item.original);
        console.log(untouched);
        for (let i = untouched.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
          untouched.splice(i, 0, item.new);
        }
        console.log(untouched);
        for (let i = 0, l = untouched.length; i < l; i++) {
          let newNode = i % 2 === 0 ? document.createTextNode("") : document.createElement("strong");
          newNode.textContent = untouched[i];
          node.parentNode.appendChild(newNode);
        }
        node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
      }
    })
  } else {
    node.childNodes.forEach(function(child, index) {
      processNode(child);
    })
  }
}

processNode(div)
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yqoxnome/4/) (partial answer)

You write in the comments on Zsolt V's answer that:

> but as you can see, the last sentence is replaced differently than the expected in the list

However, the problem is not with the code, but with the ordering of the `list` array. The problem is that you have replacements that work within one another, i.e. acting on `list[7]`, with `list[0]`:

"**This is** another random tag" (`list[7]` before)

-> "**New this is** another random tag" (`list[7]` after applying changes from `list[0]`)

You need to be mindful of the ordering.

In fact, I moved the last item in the `list` array to the top, and the results are as you've asked for.

```
var list = [{
    original: 'This is another random tag',
    new: 'This is another random tag that should be bold'
  }, {
    original: 'This is',
    new: 'New this is'
  }, {
    original: 'A list',
    new: 'New A list'
  }, {
    original: 'And I want',
    new: 'New And I want'
  }, {
    original: 'To wrap',
    new: 'New To wrap'
  }, {
    original: 'li',
    new: 'bold'
  }, {
    original: 'This',
    new: 'New This'
  }, {
    original: 'strong',
    new: 'bold'
  }

];
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yqoxnome/5/) (full answer)

Comment: Thank you for your time!!! Awesome work, one thing is that the string "This should not be bold" should not be bold at all